# Structure member declaration with " : 1 "

Tags: c, variables, structure, declaration

I found this structure in linux kernel file include/sound/soc-dapm.h .
I am confused about the declaration of its members.I looked for it on google but couldn't find any informative stuff. 
If anybody can explain why there is :1 after every variable declaration,it will be great help. Here is a part of the code.

```
struct snd_soc_dapm_widget {

    unsigned int off_val;                   /* off state value */
    unsigned char power:1;                  /* block power status */
    unsigned char invert:1;                 /* invert the power bit */
    unsigned char active:1;                 /* active stream on DAC, ADC's */
    unsigned char connected:1;              /* connected codec pin */

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's called bit field.

Comment: There's a tutorial here explaining them http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something called a ["bit field"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm). It's for memory optimization. It lets you store a type in less space than you would need otherwise.

(code from the above link).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct
{
  unsigned int age : 3;
} Age;

int main( )
{
   Age.age = 4;
   printf( "Sizeof( Age ) : %d\n", sizeof(Age) );
   printf( "Age.age : %d\n", Age.age );

   Age.age = 7;
   printf( "Age.age : %d\n", Age.age );

   Age.age = 8;
   printf( "Age.age : %d\n", Age.age );

   return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Sizeof( Age ) : 4
Age.age : 4
Age.age : 7
Age.age : 0
```

Notice how assigning to a value higher than 2<sup>3</sup> reduces the size of `Age.age` to `0`? This is because that `:3`. This also means that your `unsigned char active:1;` example is great for storing booleans: it can *only* be true or false, it can't accidentally store 255 (which happens to be the maximum value of an `unsigned char`).